# Epsilon-Delta-criterie to proof that a sectionally defined function is continious at $x=1$ and uncontinious at $x=-1$?

Tags: solution-verification, continuity

$g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 ,\quad |x|=1 \\ \frac{2}{x+1},\quad  |x|\neq 1 \end{cases}$

It is an exercise to better understand the epsilon-delta definition of continuous functions.

(i)
So I want to use the $\epsilon-\delta-$criteria to proof that $g(x)$ is continious at $x=1$.
I need to find a $\delta>0$ for any $\epsilon >0$, so that for every $x\in D$:
$|x-1|<\delta \Rightarrow |g(x)-g(1)|<\epsilon$.

$|g(x)-g(1)|= |\frac{2}{x+1}-1|=|\frac{2}{x+1}-\frac{x+1}{x+1}|=|\frac{2-(x+1)}{x+1}|=|\frac{1-x}{x+1}|=\frac{|x-1|}{|x+1|}=\frac{|x-1|}{|x|}<\frac{\delta}{|x|}$

I don't know how to get rid of  $\frac{1}{|x|}$, how can I estimate that upwards?

ii)
The second exercise is to show that $g(x)$ is not continious at $x=-1$
So I need to find a $\epsilon >0$, so that for every $\delta>0$, there is a $x\in D$, so that $|x-(-1)|=|x+1|<\delta$ and $ |g(x)-g(-1)|=|g(x)-1|\geq \epsilon$.
Choose $x=\delta +1$ and $\epsilon = 1$:

$|g(x)-g(1)|= |\frac{2}{x+1}-1|=|\frac{2}{x+1}-\frac{x+1}{x+1}|=|\frac{2-(x+1)}{x+1}|=|\frac{1-x}{x+1}|=\frac{|x-1|}{|x+1|}>\frac{|x-1|}{\delta}=\frac{|(\delta +1)-1|}{\delta}=\frac{|\delta|}{\delta}=\frac{\delta}{\delta}=1=\epsilon. $

Did I apply the criteria correctly?

PS:
I hope that my formulations correspond to the usual mathematical terminology in English-speaking countries.
English is not my native language, please correct me if you see a mistake :)

Comment: In the first part use the fact that $|x|>1-\delta 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start with continuity at $x=1$. We want $|\dfrac{2}{x+1}-1|<\epsilon$ which is equivalent to $|\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}|<\epsilon$ which is equivalent to

$x^{2}(1-\epsilon^{2})-2x(1+\epsilon^{2})+1-\epsilon^{2}<0$.

Using the roots of the binomial we get that this is equivalent to:

$\dfrac{2\epsilon^{2}-2\epsilon}{1-\epsilon^{2}}<x-1<\dfrac{2\epsilon^{2}+2\epsilon}{1-\epsilon^{2}}$.  $(1)$

It easy to check that for $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ the inequality $(1)$ holds. (Assuming e.g. $\epsilon<\dfrac{1}{2}$).

Thus we have $|x-1|<\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ implies :

$|\dfrac{2}{x+1}-1|<\epsilon$. (For $\epsilon\geq\,\dfrac{1}{2}$ the inequality holds a fortiori). So we get continuity at $x=1$.

Now proving the discontinuity at $x=-1$. All we need is to show that there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ there exists an $x$ with $|x+1|<\delta$ such that $|\dfrac{2}{x+1}-1|>\epsilon$.

Take $\epsilon=\dfrac{1}{2}$.Then for each $\delta>0$ there exists an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\dfrac{1}{n}<\delta$.

Taking $x=-1+\dfrac{1}{n}$ we get that $|\dfrac{2}{x+1}-1|=|2n-1|>\epsilon=\dfrac{1}{2}$ (choosing $n>1$).

Thus $g$ is discontinuous at $x=-1$. And we are done!

Comment: Do you mean with "using the root", that you searched for the $x$, so that $x^{2}(1-\epsilon^{2})-2x(1+\epsilon^{2})+1-\epsilon^{2}=0$
I get $x_1=\frac{1-\epsilon}{1+\epsilon},x_2=\frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}$. But how do you get to: $\dfrac{2\epsilon^{2}-2\epsilon}{1-\epsilon^{2}}<x-1<\dfrac{2\epsilon^{2}+2\epsilon}{1-\epsilon^{2}}$

Comment: You just write $x_{1}<x<x_{2}$ and subtract $1$ from all sides. I just didn't make the simplification. But the result is the same!

Comment: Ok, I understand your proof that $g$ is discontinious at $x=-1$. Is my proof of the same statement wrong? If so, why?

Comment: I think your proof is correct!